Since 24.04, closing the screen on my laptop no longer locks the session
Since I upgraded to 24.04, Ubuntu doesn't lock the session anymore when I close the screen.
I tried to force it in the file /etc/systemd/logind.conf with HandleLidSwitch=suspend but it doesn't work.
Can you help me?
